Movie where a man notices that his neighbor may be a killer
I watched this movie on TV about 7 years ago and can not remember all the details. Seems it was a US/Canadiam movie. The action took place somewhere in US.
A man (let's call him the main guy of the movie) rents a house in a suburban  community and notices that his neighbor living in the next house is a very suspicious person. He starts spying on his neighbor, and sometimes sees something strange in his yard. He asks about the neighbor with other neighbors - an old couple, but they respond that this guy is a good person and etc.
When the neighbor is out, the main guy enters his house and finds a video tape where the neighbor tortures and molestates some people. So he realizes that his neighbor is a maniac and killer.
The main guy decides to use it for his purpose. He somehow sets up another person (an enemy from his job), and the neighbor kills that person.
Finally the main guy is caught by the neighbor and the old couple with other community members tell him that the neighbor is a maniac - the community killer who does the "dirty job" - and kills those who bother the community.
Finally, the main guy begs the maniac to let him free, and proposes that he go on a long vacation. He promises that he will do the "dirty job" for the community instead of him. 

Some of it reminds me of Arlington Road.

A lot of it reminds me of "Rear Window" and the remake "Disturbia"
